# wordpress theme from scratch doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, function

I'm trying to develop a wordpress theme from scratch, but I have some problem with `function.php`. I want to add additional javascripts, but the thing is that they are not loading with the "package" and when I check the links from my browser I can see that they are not downloaded like my stylesheet

```
function humlan_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . ' 
    /css/bootstrap.min.css',false,'3.0.3','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prettyPhoto', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/css/prettyPhoto.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/css/font-awesome.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/css/animate.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/css/main.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/css/responsive.css',false,'1.1','all');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/js/jquery.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smoothscroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/js/smoothscroll.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.isotope.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . ' 
    /js/jquery.isotope.min.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.prettyPhoto', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.parallax', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/js/jquery.parallax.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', 
    array(), '20151215', true );

      if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
      }
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'humlan_scripts' );
```

The question is how do I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling `get_stylesheet_directory_uri90` to enqueue javascript?

Comment: Even if I test get_template_directory_uri () it dosn´t work for me. And I saw it on youtube, it works for him. I don´t know witch one is the correctly

Comment: You're not following the proper method of enqueue a script. Try this:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Can you show me a example from my code please?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials out there on this stuff. Try those first and then repost the question if you can't get it. You'll learn more that way anyway.

Comment: Your method should work provided `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns the same thing as `get_template_directory_uri()`.  Are you sure your files are there? :P

Comment: Okay the problem was I wrote tru instead of false. But now I got a another problem. I get this message

main.js?ver=20151215:61 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at main.js?ver=20151215:61
    at dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

This is in main

// Preloder script
jQuery(window).load(function(){'use strict';
 $(".preloader").delay(1600).fadeOut("slow").remove();
});

What is wrong with It?

Comment: replace `$` with `jQuery` everywhere in your `main.js`.  jQuery on WordPress is run in no conflict mode, this is but one of several ways to fix it.

Comment: I did that and It works byt got 13 new error with same message 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js?ver=20151215:86)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Scroll (main.js?ver=20151215:85)
    at main.js?ver=20151215:49
    at dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

Comment: Okay It works now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**wp_enqueue_style** & **wp_enqueue_script** functions always expect a URL for the enqueued file. Now when you are using **get_stylesheet_directory_uri()** so its trying to load it from **css** folder at your theme folder. So please check whether the files are presents at that location. Or else you can use the URL like "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css", so the file will be loaded from the url.

NOTE : use **get_template_directory_uri()** instead of **get_stylesheet_directory_uri()**

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a file typo mistake

Please update your  `function.php` its `functions.php`.